# How to save document or file from iOS Mail attachment to our application in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have seen that google drive is able to save document from iOS mail attachment to google drive. How to do this in our application?
I find that we can open document or pdf from iOS mail attachment to our application using UIDocumentInteractionController.
But is there any way to save that document into our application.

Comment: try share extensions

Comment: Are you sure from share extension, we can save.

Comment: the answer is below or look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ShareSheet.html

Answer (score 1):

U need to know about Extensions First and types of Extensions

please refer screenshot , In the screenshot My App is integrated with Action Extension , So by Default My App Shows up with UIActivityviewcontreoller(I can Share Images from any APP(Which Contains Images))

[image]

## Useful Links for Extensions  and screenshots for NSExtension Attributes

[image]

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-how-to-build-a-simple-action-extension--cms-22794

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/SystemExtensionKeys.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW8

### For Documents  Extension

1. Create a new Project and go to file -> create New Target -> select Action Extension 
   and in Plist 
   U need to enable NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount this to be added in Plist , count to be 1 (1 = allows attachment 1)
2. Run with Mail Application(attachment share) Ur App Shows on Action Extension

U can achieve with Share extension also not sure